# how to refresh the window in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function which will display features of an image. Once it got displayed, I want to refresh it for the next image. 
For instance if I have a window like this 
[image]

Once I click on the **Refresh Button** the window should be like this
[image]

Initially every feature values are set to zero.
How to achieve this? I have tried with `grid_forget()` it will not give me what I wanted. I don't want to clear the window, I just want to clear the entries in each of the Entry box, and I want to clear the Label too, so that I can select another image

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot of Entry widgets, like in your example, you can use the [`winfo_children()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method) method to get a list of all the children widgets of an object. Then, you can iterate through this list to reset and configure the widgets it contains:

```
root = Tk()

def clear_all():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():      # get all children of root
        if widget.winfo_class() == 'Entry':   # if the class is Entry
            widget.delete(0,END)              # reset its value
        elif widget.winfo_class() == 'Label': # get Label widgets
            widget.config(bg='green')         # and change them as well

# set up misc. widgets
for i in range(5):
    Entry(root).pack()
Label(root, height=10, width=100, bg='red').pack()
Button(root, text='Refresh', command=clear_all).pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the entry widgets to whatever default values you want:

```
# if you do not use the textvariable attribute:
self.entry1.delete(0, "end")
self.entry1.insert(0, "0")
self.entry2.delete(0, "end")
self.entry2.insert(0, "0.0")

# if you DO use the textvariable attribute:
self.entry1var.set("0")
self.entry2var.set("0.0")
```

This is all documented on the Entry man page, and in most tkinter tutorials. A good place to start when researching how to use individual widgets is effbot.org. For example, here is their page on the Entry widget: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm